# opencv android black screen even with the premissions

Tags: java, android, opencv, deep-learning, face-detection

am trying to do a face detection app with OpenCV I carefully followed a tutorial an did exact the same implementation, I added the permissions in manifest and the permission guaranteed in the java activity but still showing me a black screen I looked every where in stack overflow but did not find the answer help me please
thank you

here is my xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".third"
    >


    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView

        android:id="@+id/javaCam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

         />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

> 

and this is my java class

```
package com.example.aiProject;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class third extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static final String TAG = "third";
    JavaCameraView javaCam;
    File caseFile;
    CascadeClassifier faceDetector;
    private Mat mRgba, mGrey;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    int activeCamera = CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_BACK;

    static {
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "O

    penCV is intialised");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV is not initialised");
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.third);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Permissions granted");
        initializeCamera(javaCam, activeCamera);
    } else {
        // prompt system dialog
        Log.d(TAG, "Permission prompt");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 
    MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    javaCam = findViewById(R.id.javaCam);
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, baseCallback);
    } else {

        try {
            baseCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    javaCam.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

}


  // callback to be executed after the user has give an pproval or rejection via system prompt
 @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, 
    @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // camera can be turned on
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            initializeCamera(javaCam, activeCamera);
        } else {
            // camera will stay off
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

 private void initializeCamera(JavaCameraView javaCameraView, int activeCamera) {
    javaCameraView.setCameraPermissionGranted();
    javaCameraView.setCameraIndex(activeCamera);
    javaCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
    javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat();
    mGrey = new Mat();

}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mGrey.release();
    mRgba.release();

}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGrey = inputFrame.gray();
        // detect face
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        //portrqit mode
        Core.flip(mRgba.t(), mRgba, 1);
        Core.flip(mGrey.t(), mGrey, 1);
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(mRgba, faceDetections);
        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
                    new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                    new Scalar(255, 0, 0));

        }
        return mRgba;

    }

    private final BaseLoaderCallback baseCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) throws IOException {
            switch (status) {

                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    InputStream is = 
         getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.haarcascade_frontalface_alt2);
                    File cascadDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    caseFile = new File(cascadDir, "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(caseFile);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;

                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    }
                    fos.close();
                    is.close();
                    faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(caseFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (faceDetector.empty()) {
                        faceDetector = null;
                    } else
                        cascadDir.delete();
                    javaCam.enableView();
                }
                break;
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                }
                break;
            }

            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        }
    };

}
```

and this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.example.aiProject">

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AIPROJECT">
        <activity android:name=".third"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />

</manifest>
```

if you know another free way to do the face detection(not firebase or amazon cause they are not free for huge data) please inform me thank you

Comment: When debugging, does it enter the onCameraFrame callback? Put a breakpoint inside this method to check if frames are received.

Comment: @gioravered when putting a break point inside the method and debugging it says:          rect.width=cannot find local variable 'rect'  rect,height =cannot find local variable'rect'      rect.xcannot find local variable 'rect'    rect.y=cannot find local variable 'rect'